# lazy load in an expandable list view with over 30 thousand items

Tags: android, filter, expandablelistview, lazy-loading

1. I am looking for a solution to handle 30,000 GroupItems using an infinite scroll or lazy load within an expandable list view? how to implement it into MyCustomAdapter?

the items are loaded from a local .txt file into an array and populated to the expandable list.

2. how to handle a filter for as many items because on each keydown the app freezes, depending on which device I use.

here is my CustomAdapter:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Parent> mParent;
    private static final String TAG = "MyCustomAdapter: ";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;
    private ArrayList<Parent> arraylist;
    Context aContext;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Parent> parent){
        mParent = parent;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(parent);


    }


    @Override
    //counts the number of group/parent items so the list knows how many times calls getGroupView() method
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mParent.size();
    }

    @Override
    //counts the number of children items so the list knows how many times calls getChildView() method
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return mParent.get(i).getArrayChildren().size();
    }

    @Override
    //gets the title of each parent/group
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return mParent.get(i).getTitle();
    }

    public Object getGroupName(int i){
        return mParent.get(i).getName();
    }

    @Override
    //gets the name of each item
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return mParent.get(i).getArrayChildren().get(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    //in this method you must set the text to see the parent/group on the list
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.groupPosition = groupPosition;

        if (view == null) {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_parent, viewGroup, false);
        }

        Parent item = mParent.get(groupPosition);
        //if (DEBUG)Log.e(TAG, "Selected text: " + (item.getName()));
        TextView nameText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameValue);
        nameText.setText(item.getName());



        TextView countryLanguageGenreText = (TextView) view.findViewById((R.id.countryLanguageGenre));
        countryLanguageGenreText.setText(item.getCountryLanguageGenre());



        view.setTag(holder);

        //return the entire view
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    //in this method you must set the text to see the children on the list
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.childPosition = childPosition;
        holder.groupPosition = groupPosition;

        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_child, viewGroup, false);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_child);
        textView.setText(mParent.get(groupPosition).getArrayChildren().get(childPosition));


        view.setTag(holder);

        //return the entire view
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        /* used to make the notifyDataSetChanged() method work */
        super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }



    protected class ViewHolder {
        protected int childPosition;
        protected int groupPosition;
        protected Button button;
    }


    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        mParent.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            mParent.addAll(arraylist);
        }
        else
        {
            for (Parent wp : arraylist)
            {
                if (wp.getSearchString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    mParent.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using cursor may be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the qualities of the list view is that it gets recycled and recreated only for the visible list items. The problem is not the length of items in your list view. It is the inefficiency of reading file.

I suggest you to use a database backed design which will give the application more stability as well as you can easily get filters working.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Diyoda about importing the data from the text file into a database backed design.  Then possibly look at doing ajax like requests via droidQuery.
[Can ajax call be done in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793544/can-ajax-call-be-done-in-android)

http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/

As the user scrolls down you perform an asynchronous request for more of the data. You poll a URL as you would with jQuery ajax then pass a parameter to your adapter which gets the next set of data from your database.