# android sensor programe to send data to local database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have android program  to display the sensor data and on button click it will send to local MySQL database running with PHP as backed in wamp server.its working properly.to connect to database i have given local host or local IP address of the system which is running. now i want to send the data to same database on button click with any network connected ? what should i do ? I even tried change allow access to all edit alias  in wamp server but unable to connect. so any one suggest what to do?
thanks in advance

Comment: on button click if you are able to apply some ajax code then call a php page in that ajax code and append data to it. Now on that php page capture the data, connect to db,save to db and send success or false based on query execution.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. i am very new to android and networking can you tell me little more about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793544/can-ajax-call-be-done-in-android

Comment: i have no idea of android, i am just telling the way which is looks possible from my point of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your android app and the computer on which your php code is running are all in the same network. To do this all you can do is create wifi hotspot using one of the devices and connect the other to the same wifi (Create hotspot in your mobile, which is running the app and connect your computer to the same wifi hotspot. Next open command prompt and execute **ipconfig**. Use the IP address that you got when you connected your computer to mobile hotspot).

---

OR

---

You can host your backend code on some servers and use the IP address in your android app(This is more as useful as you can use your android app from any network)