# How to make API calls using Ajax in android?

Tags: android, ajax, api, android-studio, kotlin

I am given a task to create an android app where i need to call an API but using AJAX.
I have been doing this using Retrofit till now but don't know how to use AJAX in kotlin or java.
Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can ajax call be done in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793544/can-ajax-call-be-done-in-android)

Comment: No . It is  very confusing and i wanted to use it in java or kotlin.